# how get value from php and use in javascript

Tags: php, javascript, var

As i have define the code  this way for rating

```
<?php foreach($rating as $ratingValue):
$total = @round($ratingValue->TOT_RATING / $ratingValue->TOTAL_VOTER ,1);
echo $total."/10";
endforeach;
?>
```

as from above php code it will give the total ratin and then

starts javascript where javascript takes the total rating as $total where i have defined below

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

var totalRating = <?php echo $total;?>;
var baseUrl = "<?php echo base_url();?>";
$(function() {
$("#rating_simple1").webwidget_rating_sex({
rating_star_length: '5',
rating_initial_value: totalRating,
rating_function_name: '', //this is function name for click
directory: baseUrl+'./assets/frontend/images/'
});
});
</script>
```

when i run it it will shows error message lik this

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

var totalRating = <div style="border:1px solid #990000;padding-left:20px;margin:0 0 10px 0;">

<h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>

<p>Severity: Notice</p>
<p>Message:  Undefined variable: total</p>
<p>Filename: views/detail.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 69</p>

</div>;
var baseUrl = "http://localhost/aka/";
 $(function() {
 $("#rating_simple1").webwidget_rating_sex({
 rating_star_length: '5',
 rating_initial_value: totalRating,
 rating_function_name: '', //this is function name for click
 directory: baseUrl+'./assets/frontend/images/'
  });
  });
  </script>
```

please help me to solve it so that i can do my rating

Comment: "Message:  Undefined variable: total", "Line Number: 69"; perhaps you should check line 69 to see if you're actually defining total.

Comment: better set a value in a hidden field in your HTML and get the value of that hidden field using jQuery in your Javascript code

Comment: See the total variable at Line Number: 69 it is undefined means not declared and you are using this variable in the code

Comment: and you should always use document.ready function

Answer (score 0):

```
$ratingValue->TOT_RATING 

TOT_RATING  <<< explain this please 

$ratingValue->TOTAL_VOTER 

TOTAL_VOTER  <<< explain this please 

$total = @round($ratingValue->TOT_RATING / $ratingValue->TOTAL_VOTER ,1);
```

you are using the ( foreach ) variables as classes

Comment: TOT_RATING is the field name from table TOTAL_VOTER is the total of all TOT_RATING